# How to call an Arraylist method?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I have a method:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer>Iterate(int n){
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);{
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
            Integer r = rand.nextInt() %113;
            numbers.add(r);
            Collections.sort(numbers);
        }}
```

And I want to use other methods on this Array to find out certain things about the numbers.

But I can't figure out to call the Arraylist in `public static void main(String [] args)`.

I've tried things like:

```
System.out.println( numbers.methodname);
```

And things like that, but Eclipse says numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
So what's the proper way to call the ArrayList so a method can effect it?

Comment: Declare `numbers` outside of the method `Iterate`. As it is now, only the method `Iterate` has access to that variable.

Comment: Please please please ***please*** read a basic guide to OOP or Java...

Comment: Your method is declared as returning an ArrayList<Integer>, so presumably you do return it, right? And you call it from main, right? What do you assign its return value to, in main?

Comment: Also, why do you sort the list every time you add a number to it?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you ever return an `ArrayList<Integer>` in your method. Just return `numbers` in your method and in `main` do something like `ArrayList<Integer> list = Iterate(someValue)`. Then you can call methods on `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to make your method return the `ArrayList` that it creates, so that it can be used by whatever method called your method.  You've already got the right method signature - that is, the first line, where it says

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> Iterate(int n){
```

which means that the method will return something of type `ArrayList<Integer>`.  Now you need to add this line to the bottom of the method, before the last `}`.

```
return numbers;
```

Now, within your `main` method, or whatever other method calls this one, you can write something like

```
ArrayList<Integer> returnedList = Iterate(10);
```

or something similar, depending on what number you want to pass to the method.  This declares a variable called `returnedList`, calls the method, and assigns the `ArrayList` that's returned by the method, to the variable that you declared.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers` needs to be declared outside of your method for other methods to be able to access it. If you declare a variable inside a method, its scope is the method it was declared in.

You can still initialize the variable inside the method if you so choose, but the declaration has to be made outside, like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = null;

public static ArrayList<Integer> Iterate(int n){
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried this it said: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field numbers"

Comment: short answer to make it work: `static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = null;`
--------------------------------
good answer: After you're done with this assignment or whatever it is, I suggest you read up or watch tutorials on basic OOP. Take it from someone who's rushed through assignments before too, you won't make it very far if you don't truly understand what you're coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the numbers variable in the Iterate method, it does not exist outside the scope of that method.  This means that while you're in main, you cannot access that variable.  If you want to access a variable in main, it needs to be declared in main.